# Is it possible to have multiple py3 version?

Tags: python, anaconda

I wanted to install python 3.4. But I don't want to downgrade my Python3.5. Is it possible to have both of them?

How to get that using conda?

Answer (score 2):

conda provides support for different versions of python, you can create a different environment by

```
conda create -n python34 python=3.4 anaconda
```

Then activate the environment with

```
acitvate python34
```